# NodeJS: Get folders size recursively

Tags: javascript, node.js, directory

I want to scan all files/directories of a given folder and calculate it's sizes. It should only output until X folders depth though.

Example folder structure:

```
├── folder1
│   ├── folder1
│   │   ├── file1.txt
│   │   ├── file2.txt
│   │   └── folder1
│   └── folder2
│       ├── file1.txt
│       └── file2.txt
└── folder2
    ├── folder1
    │   ├── file1.txt
    │   ├── file2.txt
    │   └── folder1
    └── folder2
        ├── file1.txt
        └── file2.txt
```

I took some time and searched the internet but all answers looked unreasonably complicated.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO isn’t here to write trivial code for people who don’t want to be bothered to figure it out. It’s here to help with specific problems for people who have attempted but need further guidance.

Comment: @peteb - If you're doing this with asynchronous fs apis, this is not trivial code and it's a reasonable, non-trivial question.  It would be good if the OP showed what they tried and where they got stuck.

Comment: @jfriend00 That's true about async directory traversals but, from what I can tell from the question, the OP doesn't seem to have tried anything (sync or async). I'd be happy to remove the close & down vote if the question improves.

Comment: @peteb i think you should [read this](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/06/21/rolling-out-the-welcome-wagon-june-update/), you are definetly right, but I think you could put that into a more friendly wording ...

Comment: @JonasW. I hear ya but, I wasn't trying to be snarky or not nice as described in the link you provided. It was a Close Vote - "Other Reason" that was meant to be direct with why I felt this question should be closed, not a straight up nonconstructive comment. Either way, the post was insightful as to SO's position going forward regarding Community interactions, thanks for sharing that.

Answer (score -1):

I wont write the code for you but you can do this with:

https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html

readdir/readdirSync and fs.stats and stats.isDirectory.  The rest is up to you it's a fairly simple thing to do to use those to loop through and check each file/folder.